# Equivalence of tensor field definitions

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, coordinate-systems, tensors

In physics tensor fields are often defined in a different way than in math. I am trying to establish an equivalence between the definitions.

In math a tensor field of type $(k,l)$ on a manifold $M$ is an assignment of a tensor of type $(k,l)$ on the tangent space $T_p M$ for every $p\in M$. A tensor of type $(k,l)$ on a vector space $V$ being a multilinear function $(V^*)^k \times V^l\to \mathbb{R}$.

In physics a tensor field is often defined by a transformation law. If $(u^i)_i$ and $(u'^i)_i$ are two local coordinate systems on coordinate neighbourhoods $U$ and $U'$ of $M$ respectively, a tensor field $T$ on $M$ is defined as an object whose components transform as: 
$$T'\hphantom{'}^{i_1 \dots i_k}_{j_1 \dots j_l} = 
\frac{\partial u'^{i_1}}{\partial u^{a_1}} \dots
\frac{\partial u'^{i_k}}{\partial u^{a_k}} 
\frac{\partial u^{b_1}}{\partial u'^{j_1}} \dots
\frac{\partial u^{b_1}}{\partial u'^{j_l}} 
T^{a_1 \dots a_k}_{b_1 \dots b_l}$$

The only way to make sense of this definition is, I think, to let T be an assignment of a map $((T_p M)^*)^k \times (T_p M)^l\to \mathbb{R}$ to every point $p\in M$, but not necessarily a multilinear one.

Due to the multilinearity the math definition implies the physics definition immediately. What's left to prove is thus that the maps from the physics definition are multilinear.

My idea was the following. Let $(u^i)_i$ be a local coordinate system and let $(e_i)_i$ be the associated basis of $T_p M$ and $(\epsilon ^i)_i$ its dual basis. Suppose T is a $(1,1)$ tensor field from the physics definition and suppose we want to show $T(\epsilon ^2 , 2 e_1)=2T(\epsilon ^2 , e_1)$.  Then we can define a new coordinates by $u'^1=\frac{1}{2}u^1$ and $u'^i= u^i$ for all other $i$. Then we get: 
$$T(\epsilon ^2 , 2 e_1) = T(\epsilon' ^2 , e'_1) = T'^2_1 
= \frac{\partial u'^2}{\partial u^a}\frac{\partial u^b}{\partial u'^1}T^a_b
= \frac{\partial u'^2}{\partial u^2}\frac{\partial u^1}{\partial u'^1}T^2_1
= 2T^2_1 = 2T(\epsilon ^2 , e_1)$$
and we are done.

The only problem is that this approach doesn't work when instead of $T^2_1$ we would look at e.g. $T^1_1$, since the dual basis vector used then transforms along with the basis vector. So when $2e_1=e'_1$ then $\epsilon_1=2\epsilon'_1$ and the trick cannot be used.

Have I understood the physics defintion correctly and if so, is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: The only definition of tensor field I have encountered is: as a section in the tensor bundle $(T^*M)^{\otimes k}\otimes (TM)^{\otimes l}$

Comment: That is indeed a more mathematically sophisticated definition. I'm trying to keep away from bundles however because they are still a bit out of my league. But even using the bundle definition,  the question of how to make sense of this definition in terms of a transformation rule, found in nearly every physics book on (general) relativity, keeps standing for me.

Comment: The thing, I think, is that physicists prefer looking at things in bases. Mathematicians don't. Therefore, a mathematician defines a tensor "simply as a vector" (almost, at least. But not as a map, as you said), which of course has a well-defined transformation law, e.g.  \begin{align*}\omega &= \omega^i_j\partial_i\otimes dx^j = \omega^i_j (\partial_i\tilde{x}^m)(\tilde{\partial}_n x^j) \tilde{\partial}_m\otimes d\tilde{x}^n\\
&=\tilde{\omega}^m_n \tilde{\partial}_m\otimes d\tilde{x}^n
\end{align*} I hope my indices aren't mixed up.
Compare the two.

Comment: I agree with you on the transformation properties of tensors in the mathematical perspective. My question however is if this transformation property can somehow be used to reobtain the multilinearity of tensors in the physical perspective. But maybe, physicists just implicitly assume multilinearity and just don't bother to mention it. It that case, the definitions are automatically equivalent.

Comment: Maybe I should ask this on the physics page of stack exchange

Comment: As a side note, I thought that $(V^*)^{\otimes k}\otimes V^{\otimes l}$ is isomorphic to $Mult((V^*)^k \times V^l,\mathbb{R})$, ie the set of multilinear maps. Thats why you can define tensors as maps.

Comment: Oh, the $k$ and $l$ need to be switched in one of the two sets in my previous comment

Comment: I'm born and raised a physicist, and I have not encountered your definition, sorry. What are your sources for that? Also, do you know how the tensor product works on a mathematical level (quotient of free vector space, etc)? That is actually the stuff that we weren't taught (being physicists), and I only learned really late.

Comment: In case you want ot look this kind of things up: a detailed discussion of the relationships between the various approaches is given in Spivak's comprehensive introduction to Differential Geometry.